# How to remove a variable?

Tags: errors, compiling, variable

Is there a way to delete a variable so that any future references would raise an undefined control sequence error? I am dealing with a big document that has a lot of custom variables and macros with very similar spelling. I would like to irreversibly remove those that I am sure will not appear later in the document to effectively detect typos rather than end up with a document filled with egregious errors.

Answer (score 3):

TeX doesn't really have anything calld variables but you can undefine a control sequence by `\let` it to any undefined command, conventioally `\undefined` and `\@undefined` are left undefined for this use, so:

```
\def\abc{xyz}
\abc
\let\abc\undefined
\abc % error
```

But `\undefined` here is not a special keyword, and only works by convention that it is not defined so

```
\def\abc{xyz}
\abc
\let\abc\someothercommandwithnodefinition
\abc % error
```

would be the same